# Безопасно переименовать колонку

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как автоматизировать переименование колонки, чтобы автоматически обновились все ключи, её использования во вью, хранимых процедурах и во всех остальных местах?

В описиании [sp_rename](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) говорится, что она не обновляет ссылки:

> Renaming an object such as a table or column will not automatically rename references to that object. You must modify any objects that reference the renamed object manually. For example, if you rename a table column and that column is referenced in a trigger, you must modify the trigger to reflect the new column name. Use [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to list dependencies on the object before renaming it.

Comment: Никак, и обновление индекса имеется ввиду при переименовании констрейнта, а не колонки.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, хм.. т. е. этот абзац вообще не про переименование колонки? Я думал, имеется в виду, если мы переименовываем колонку, входящую в индекс, то он будет указывать на новую колонку. А получается, речь о том, что мы переименовываем сам индекс и он просто не пересоздаётся с нуля?

Comment: Речь о том, что когда создается PK или UNIQUE constraint, то создается индекс с тем же именем, и в случае переименования constraint-а этот индекс будет тоже переименован

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, тогда подкорректировал вопрос.

Comment: Угу... добыли тулзу, запустили, переименовали всё по цепочке. А потом руками лопатим все процедуры и функции, особенно где динамический SQL... и молимся, что ничего не пропустили. Ну это так, на всякий случай.

Answer (score 2):

У **RedGate** есть тула **SQL Prompt**, в ней есть фича **Smart Rename**.

Процесс переименования:

1. В обозревателе объектов **SSMS**  находим колонку которую требуется переименовать, нажимаем ПКМ на нее, находим пункт **Smart Rename**.
2. В появившемся окне вводим новое имя колонки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Далее нажмите **Next** и вы получите превью скрипта на изменение объекта + зависимых объектов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Далее наживаем **View Script** и получаем код готовый для выполнения необходимых изменений.

Более подробно о инструменте и о том как с ним работать [тут](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/refactoring-databases-with-sql-prompt).